# Run Mailhog installed by Nix

Tags: nix

I'm trying run [Mailhog](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog) on Gitpod.

Here's what I currently achieved, but still looking into automating it:

1. Install on Gitpod with `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.mailhog`.
2. Look at the nixstore path, and manually run it (e.g. `/nix/store/9v57rdcmknfryp2brf09z9wp2i90h63q-MailHog-1.0.1/bin/MailHog`)

My question is how can I run it without harcoding the nixstore path? `nix-shell --run 'mailhog'` resulted with the error `/tmp/nix-shell-4369-0/rc: line 1: mailhog: command not found`

Comment: `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.mailhog` should be sufficient to bring `MailHog` in your PATH. So literally just `MailHog` should be sufficient to run it.

Comment: It worked once I changed on gitpod.yaml the `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.mailhog` to be under `before` instead of `init` - so now it works on pre-built tasks as-well